# Adding innerHTML in for loop in order to generate a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, linkedin-api

I working on a script to display a company's status updates via the LinkedIn api. The script works as such, but I can't make my generated list item appear inside `<ul></ul>` tags. Right now my code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: my_client_id
  onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
  authorize: true 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onLinkedInLoad() {
  IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
}

function onLinkedInAuth() {
  var cpnyID = 2414183; //LinkedIn's testDevCo
  IN.API.Raw("/companies/" + cpnyID + "/updates?event-type=status-update&start=0&count=20&format=json")
    .result(displayCompanyUpdates);
}

function displayCompanyUpdates(result) {
  var div = document.getElementById("displayUpdates");

  div.innerHTML = "<ul>";

  var resValues = result.values;
  for (var i in resValues) {

    var share = resValues[i].updateContent.companyStatusUpdate.share;
    var content = share.content;
    var isTitled = content,
      isLinked = content,
      isDescription = content,
      isThumbnail = content;

    if (isTitled) {
      var title = share.content.title;
    } else {
      var title = "Custom title";
    }

    if (isLinked) {
      var link = share.content.shortenedUrl;
    } else {
      var link = "#";
    }

    if (isDescription) {
      var description = isDescription.description;
    } else {
      var description = "No description";
    }

    if (isThumbnail) {
      var thumbnailUrl = share.content.thumbnailUrl;
    } else {
      var thumbnailUrl = "http://placehold.it/60x60";
    }

    if (share) {
      var content = "<a target='_blank' href=" + link + ">" + title + "</a><br>" + description;
      div.innerHTML += "<li><img src='" + thumbnailUrl + "' alt=''>" + content + "</li>";
    }
    console.log(share);
  }

  div.innerHTML += "</ul>";
}
</script>
```

And it generates this html:

```
<div id="displayUpdates">
    <ul></ul>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
</div>
```

What do I need to change in order to get the list items inside the ul?
Could this be done more easily with jQuery?

Comment: Fiddle looks terrible...:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that is a correct result as you are using `innerHTML` to replace the existing content, although you are appending to it with `+=` but when you do this `div.innerHTML = "<ul>";` browser sees that there is a opened `ul` and when it doesn't find it's descendants it automatically closes it.

You should use `innerHTML` only when the loop stops:

```js
function displayCompanyUpdates(result) {
  var div = document.getElementById("displayUpdates");

  var el = "<ul>"; // <----open a ul here

  var resValues = result.values;
  for (var i in resValues) {

    var share = resValues[i].updateContent.companyStatusUpdate.share;
    var content = share.content;
    var isTitled = content,
      isLinked = content,
      isDescription = content,
      isThumbnail = content;

    if (isTitled) {
      var title = share.content.title;
    } else {
      var title = "Custom title";
    }

    if (isLinked) {
      var link = share.content.shortenedUrl;
    } else {
      var link = "#";
    }

    if (isDescription) {
      var description = isDescription.description;
    } else {
      var description = "No description";
    }

    if (isThumbnail) {
      var thumbnailUrl = share.content.thumbnailUrl;
    } else {
      var thumbnailUrl = "http://placehold.it/60x60";
    }

    if (share) {
      var content = "<a target='_blank' href=" + link + ">" + title + "</a><br>" + description;
     el += "<li><img src='" + thumbnailUrl + "' alt=''>" + content + "</li>"; // add list items
    }
    console.log(share);
  }

  el += "</ul>"; /// <------close the ul here

  div.innerHTML = el; // <------here
}
```

Comment: Little explanation about how browser works if only opening `tag` is added in DOM will be helpful!

Comment: @RayonDabre that is what i was adding in the mean time.

Comment: Yeah..It looks perfect now!

Comment: @Jai Thanks a lot for the fix and the explanation. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to so this in raw Javascript, you could do it by creating each parent element and changing the inner HTML of the children, something like:

```
var div = document.getElementById("displayUpdates");
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
var resValues = result.values;
for (var i in resValues) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    // populate innerHTML of "li"
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
div.appendChild(ul);
```

Comment: Yeah, I feel like that's how I'd deal with keeping the hierarchy straight without a template engine?

Comment: I guess `var a = ''; a += 'Element'; parent.innerHTML = a` is more optimal solution...

Comment: It's only really affecting the DOM at the final appendChild there, so you're not really incurring the performance hit of repeatedly appending